# Portfilio and Showcase Area

Tags: discussion

It would be really great to have an area where we can showcase Drupal features or Drupal sites that we have created with help from the Drupal Answers community.

It might actually be really resourceful because you could explain certain features, reference Stack exchange questions that resolved certain issues or provided special functionality, and further you could credit and thank people in the community for their involvement.

Obviously one of the short fallings could be people trying to just gain awareness of their site. With good moderation that ensures people who post cite the community and  answers that helped achieved their solution, I think it could be a valuable resource.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: BTW in case you haven't come across it before, downvotes on meta site are different...they just mean someone disagrees with your proposal

Comment: Also, the meta site doesn't have its own reputation, and you don't lose reputation when you are down-voted. Votes simply mean users agree/don't agree with the idea you are suggesting, which is one of the meaning of voting in the main site too ("this question is not useful").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange allows each site to vote on promotion ads that would be then visible on the main site, where you normally see a (quasi) random question taken from other Stack Exchange: Users suggest an ad about interesting Drupal tools, events or conferences, and everything the community would be interested in. The proposed ads are then voted, and if they get enough votes, the ad is added to our site. (See [Community Promotion Ads - 2012](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/592/community-promotion-ads-2012).)

As far as I can say, we don't have specific ads for our site, except maybe the one about the Twitter account for *Drupal Answers*.
Something that required users to propose (or vote for proposed) ads was apparently not successful. I think that requiring users to moderate a list of web sites to verify the users are not simply promoting their own site would not be successful too, and it would be also be undesirable because:

- It would take away resources from moderating the site
- It would duplicate [the showcases](https://drupal.org/case-studies) already present in Drupal.org

The idea itself is not bad; its implementation is not possible. Being a site maintainer on Drupal.org, and having followed some requests to add showcases on Drupal.org, I know it requires time to check the showcase, and report what needs to be changed. In this case, the difficult part would be understand if the site development has really taken benefit from a question asked on *Drupal Answers*. Differently, everybody could claim a question helped in building a site, and nobody could verify that.

If a question helped you building a site, you can:

- Up-vote the question, and the answer that helped you
- Offer a bounty to the question, and assign it to the answer that helped you

Answer (score 4):

This would really detract from the site as being Q&A focused.

You *are* free to put in links in the About section on your profile page, and also list your website.

Personally, I do look at these when I see answers from people I don't recognize.  I helps me gauge whether someone is a hobbyist / enthusiast / site owner / Drupal professional.