# How to facilitate contributing back better?

Tags: discussion

Following [How can I make my brand new module dependent on a minimal version of Drupal 7 that's required for it to work OK?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58425/module-that-requires-a-specific-version-of-drupal/58462#58462) I have edited the relevant handbook page (but why me?) but noone yet followed up with a simple documentation patch against `hook_requirements`. How contributing back could be encouraged more?

Comment: Not an answer to the question but that's my bad it completely slipped my mind. I'll get it applied over the weekend

Comment: I kinda have to hold my hand up to dropping the ball on this too.  I read your comment late at night on my tablet and completely forgot to do anything about it!

Comment: I created http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59457 so we have something to point people to in these situations.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from suggesting to contribute a patch when a question about a hook/function/method makes clear that the documentation needs to be changed, the other alternative would be creating an ad about contributing back to Drupal, with a link to a page that explains how contributions to Drupal/Drupal.org can be done.

See [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/community-promotion-ads-2013).